# Is there a way to run a controller action and not change current view

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have view that consists of records from a database along with an icon (green plus box).  When the icon is pressed, I add the record along with some other data to another table and turn the icon to a red plus box.

AT that point, i am done.  I don't want to render the view again because that causes the data to read from the database again and building the view model then rendering the data.

i can't find a way simply to store the data and quit.

```html
Snippet from ViewBatters.cshtml

@foreach (var item in Model.BatterStats) {

<tr class="flex-row">
  <td class="details-control" id="addPlayer">
    <a class="nav-link" asp-action="AddBatter" asp-controller="Players" asp-route-franchiseId="@Model.FranchiseId" asp-route-playerId="@item.PlayerId">
      <i class="fa fa-plus-square" style="color:green;cursor:pointer;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are plenty ...
partial view

childactiononly atrib....

you can call these action via ajax requests..

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Load-Render-Partial-View-in-DIV-using-AJAX-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Comment: I had a feeling the answer lies in javascript...thank you.